How to raise multiple edges with linear falloff ending exactly on a particular edge
I'm starting from here:

And I want to get there:

There must be an easy way to do it but I can't find it...
I dissolved the two middle edges and the four under to make a big brick. Then I moved the side edge up. Then I made the cut again using ✲ CtrlR on the top face. To finally join the vertices vertically.
I tried proportional editing but it selected way more vertices than I wanted.
I tried to move the side edge first then align the vertices somehow but that was tricky.
Is there an easy way to do it?

Why overcomplicate? Just select the left most edge then press G Z 3 then select the 2nd edge and G Z 2 and then select 3rd edge G Z 1 or any other linear values instead of 3,2,1.

@HarryMcKenzie I imagine sometimes he will have e.g. 32 edge loops to modify this way. The duplicate is very reasonable at least if you don't have multiple slopes in parallel.

@MarkusvonBroady oh yeah didnt think about that haha. wait how did you add an answer? I thought this was closed  40 min ago XD

@HarryMcKenzie I have secret admin privileges don't tell anyone.

@MarkusvonBroady reported~! XD

Hi, Thanks for your answers. So the best way is proportional editing with hide.. I hoped for something easier like based on the active edge.
The main issue i have with the other aligning solutions (including setting Z value manually) is that i can't estimate how it will sort out and have to test until it looks good. My way allowed me to move the vertices and adjust the Z value on the fly. Also thx for the precision test, very interesting even if i don't know python yet!

OK, since previous revision was too complicated :D

Hide geometry you don't want to move except the one nearest vertex to the element you will be moving directly.
Click on the vertex you intend to move directly, then ⬆ Shift+click on the one vertex you don't want to move.
⬆ ShiftF4 to switch to Python console and paste the following:

import bmesh;h=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(C.object.data).select_history;C.scene.tool_settings.proportional_distance=(h[0].co-h[1].co).length;C.area.type='VIEW_3D';

↩ Enter to return to 3D viewport
Now you can move the chosen element and the Proportional Size should be just right.



@GordonBrinkmann define "accurate", if you start with uneven coordinates as you usually do, there's really no difference in the last example. And it's not that complicated too, it's just 4 different approaches packed to one.
